# Assigning a variable as I am passing it

Tags: java, standards

```
if (someString != null && map.containsKey(someString = someString.toLowerCase()))
```

I am wondering if this would be considered a good or a bad way to assign my string value. I believe I am doubling the use of the null check by writing the code this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I can see there is if you mistakenly got `==` instead of `=`, it will be a boolean value, and can give you unexpected result, because it will not show you `Compiler Error`, and the condition will never get true.

`Map.containsKey` will always return `false` - `No Compiler Error`, No `Runtime Exception`, just `false` result everytime, and it would make your life hell searching for the issue: -

```
if (someString != null && map.containsKey(someString == someString.toLowerCase()))
```

Ideally, you should avoid using it like that. The code is less readable when you assign it that way. Also, it is not guaranteed that you don't do any `typing mistake`. So, better to avoid using it that way.

Comment: Well if `map` was a Map<String> this would let the compiler catch that mistake (still think it's a bad idea)

Comment: no its not I am intentionnally assigning the lower case value

Comment: Yeah that's right. But I just said, that if you by mistake add `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: @JasonSperske.. No, it won't nbe catched by compiler. `Map.containsKey` method takes `Object` as parameter.

Comment: i guess I would end up with a runtime exception!

Comment: @Stainedart.. No it will not be a runtime exception. But you will never get that condition true. `containsKey` will keep on returning `false`.

Comment: Look at the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) I see what you mean.  Wow, even with Generics that wouldn't be caught, I wonder why they didn't make it `containsKey(K key)`

Comment: @JasonSperske.. Actually not sure, but might be to allow to check for `subtypes`. Anyways, glad that you got the point. :)

Comment: refactoring not taking risk on this!

Comment: @Stainedart.. haha :) Sure you should not take risk, not at least when it will not add anything to performance.

Answer (score 2):

I would say bad because it hides your intent, which is more important when someone else is looking at your code.  There is no performance improvement, just a readability loss.  Also in I'm so used to avoiding this that I didn't even know that this even works in Java (I usually see this in PHP scripts)

Comment: this actually works no problem I had unit tested it to make sure but its true that readability is a bitch in this case

Answer (score 0):

The `containsKey` method in Java expects anything that implements `Object` as a parameter. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) you can find it.

The first mistake is to send an assignment as a parameter, that should be done apart OR just send the `someString.toLowerCase()` as a parameter.

Then, nesting `if` conditionals defines your priority when executing code, increasing also readibility and probably preventing other strange mistakes that eventually can appear, but that also depends on what the rest of your program does.